# GoogleDrive API file Upload

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to upload a file using a Google Drive API, Even after program execution complete the file is missing in the Google Drive.

```
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

Client_Secret = 'client_secret.json'
API_name = 'drive'
API_ver = 'v3'
Scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

service = Create_Service(Client_Secret,API_name,API_ver,Scope)


file_metadata = {'name': 'download.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('./download.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print ('File ID: %s' % file.get('status'))
```

After executing the code I am able to get fileId at the end of Program.
But not able to find the upload file in my drive.

```
client_secret.json-drive-v3-(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],)
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
drive service created successfully
File ID: 1UoTUr7kKh6fN_usX1FXOvCM4dbD2hx9e
```

Have anyone experienced this kind of problem...?

Comment: any chance you are using a service account?

Comment: Im using a Normal account, This code was working suddenly it stopped uploading but i get a file id. What do you mean by service account

Comment: Well its returning a file id which means that it is uploading.    This would suggest that you have logged in with a different user then you are checking on the web application.    Try doing a file.list its there.   Then try a about.get it will tell you who you are.

Comment: there was an authentication error everything is right

Comment: Have you solved your issue then?